# Appdynamics monitor URL/page availability

Tags: appdynamics, apm

Im trying to monitor a page availability with Appdynamics
I have an IIS server with one site and several applications. 
Appdynamics .Net agent 20.4.1 installed on the monitored server

each application has a appName.svc web page that I can call to check if the service is up.

Im trying `AppDynamics Extension for URL Monitoring` and followed the installation instructions.

I can see in `Metric browser` the URL monitor section, under that I see 'Metric Uploaded'.

where do I see indication that a URl is down/up?
can I monitor multiple URLs, as i did in yml file?

**config.yml** file section looks like this:

```
sites:
     #No authentication, with a pattern to match
   - name:     ReportService.svc
     url:      https://serverName/Reports/ReportService.svc
     followRedirects: false
     groupName: MySites
     
   - name:     DigitalService.svc
     url:      http://serverName/Digital/DigitalService.svc
     followRedirects: false
     groupName: MySites
     
   - name:     EmailService.svc
     url:      http://serverName/Email/EmailService.svc
     followRedirects: false
     groupName: MySites
```

log:

```
[Monitor-Task-Thread1] 29 Aug 2020 11:04:05,831 ERROR URLMonitorTask-URL Monitor - Unexpected error while running the URL Monitor
com.singularity.ee.agent.systemagent.api.exception.TaskExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.appdynamics.extensions.urlmonitor.config.RequestConfig.setClientForSite(RequestConfig.java:71) ~[?:?]
at com.appdynamics.extensions.urlmonitor.URLMonitorTask.run(URLMonitorTask.java:79) [?:?]
at com.appdynamics.extensions.TasksExecutionServiceProvider$1.run(TasksExecutionServiceProvider.java:48) [?:?]
at com.appdynamics.extensions.executorservice.MonitorThreadPoolExecutor$TaskRunnable.run(MonitorThreadPoolExecutor.java:113) [?:?]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_241]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_241]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.appdynamics.extensions.urlmonitor.config.RequestConfig.setClientForSite(RequestConfig.java:55) ~[?:?]
... 8 more
[Monitor-Task-Thread1] 29 Aug 2020 11:04:05,831 INFO URLMonitorTask-URL Monitor - All tasks for URL Monitor finished
[Monitor-Task-Thread1] 29 Aug 2020 11:04:05,831 INFO MetricWriteHelper-URL Monitor - Finished executing URL Monitor at 2020-08-29 11:04:05 IDT
[Monitor-Task-Thread1] 29 Aug 2020 11:04:05,831 INFO MetricWriteHelper-URL Monitor - Total time taken to execute URL Monitor : 0 ms
[Monitor-Task-Thread1] 29 Aug 2020 11:04:05,831 INFO ABaseMonitor - Finished processing all tasks in the job for URL Monitor
[pool-10-thread-2] 29 Aug 2020 11:04:09,628 INFO MetricLimitCheck-URL Monitor - Starting MetricLimitCheck
[pool-10-thread-2] 29 Aug 2020 11:04:09,628 INFO PathResolver-URL Monitor - Install dir resolved to C:\Program Files\AppDynamics\machineagent
[pool-10-thread-1] 29 Aug 2020 11:04:09,628 INFO MachineAgentAvailabilityCheck-URL Monitor - Starting MachineAgentAvailabilityCheck
[pool-10-thread-1] 29 Aug 2020 11:04:09,628 INFO MachineAgentAvailabilityCheck-URL Monitor - SIM is enabled, not checking MachineAgent availability metric
[pool-10-thread-2] 29 Aug 2020 11:04:11,175 INFO MetricLimitCheck-URL Monitor - MetricLimitCheck took 1547 ms to complete 
[pool-10-thread-2] 29 Aug 2020 11:04:29,629 INFO MetricLimitCheck-URL Monitor - Starting MetricLimitCheck
[pool-10-thread-2] 29 Aug 2020 11:04:29,629 INFO PathResolver-URL Monitor - Install dir resolved to C:\Program Files\AppDynamics\machineagent
[pool-10-thread-2] 29 Aug 2020 11:04:31,332 INFO MetricLimitCheck-URL Monitor - MetricLimitCheck took 1703 ms to complete 
[pool-10-thread-1] 29 Aug 2020 11:04:49,629 INFO MetricLimitCheck-URL Monitor - Starting MetricLimitCheck
[pool-10-thread-1] 29 Aug 2020 11:04:49,629 INFO PathResolver-URL Monitor - Install dir resolved to C:\Program Files\AppDynamics\machineagent
[pool-10-thread-1] 29 Aug 2020 11:04:51,254 INFO MetricLimitCheck-URL Monitor - MetricLimitCheck took 1625 ms to complete
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved here: https://community.appdynamics.com/t5/Java-Java-Agent-Installation-JVM/monitor-URL-page-availability/td-p/40904

Summary:

- Question did not contain full config.yml contents
- Lots of default config needed commenting out as below

```
    # Patterns to be matched, multiple patterns(to be matched) can be configured for a given site
     #matchPatterns:
     #- name: 
     #  type: 
     #  pattern: 

   #- name:     
   #  url:      
   #  authType: 

  # Basic Authentication with password encryption
   #- name:       
   #  url:        
   #  username:   
   #  password:   
   #  encryptionKey: ""
   #  encryptedPassword: ""
   #  authType: 

   #- name:     
   #  url:      

  #NTLM Auth Sample Configuration
   #- name:     
   #  url:      
   #  username: 
   #  password: 
   #  authType: 

     # Client Cert Auth Sample Configuration
   #- name:         
   #  url:          
   #  password:     
   #  authType:     
   #  keyStoreType: 
   #  keyStorePath: 
   #  keyStorePassword: 
   #  trustStorePath: 
   #  trustStorePassword: 

     #POST request sample configuration
   #- name:     
   #  url:      
   #  username:
   #  password:
   #  connectTimeout: 60000
   #  usePreemptiveAuth: 
   #  method:   
   #  headers:
   #    Content-Type: application/json
   #  requestPayloadFile: src/test/resources/conf/postrequestPayloadFile
   #  matchPatterns:
   #    - name:       Error
   #      type:       substring
   #      pattern:    Error 400

     #Proxy Configuration
   #- name:     
   #  url:      
   #  groupName: 
   #  proxyConfig:
   #    host: ""
   #    port: 
   #    username: ""
   #    password: ""
```